# Where can be ECDsaCryptoServiceProvider class found

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, msdn, ecdsa

I've been following this sample about singing xml documents with c# using RSACryptoServiceProvider.

What I need is to use this sample with ECDsaCryptoServiceProvider, found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdsacryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.102%29.aspx

As msdn say, it should be found under System.Security.Cryptography, the problem is that I cannot see that class under System.Security.Cryptography.

Does someone knows how can I use that class? Should I use a "special" version of .net framework? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only find `ECDsaCryptoServiceProvider` in preview documentation and micro framework. `ECDsaCng` exists in the normal framework, so consider using that one instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only ".NET Micro Framework 4.3"
This is for microcontroler-devices before the IOT-wave came out.